# H2 error SQLException: 90079 Schema ??? not found; when interpreting the table alias as schema name?

Tags: sql, h2

I am having problems with a SELECT in H2 database, using a table alias.

The database is in-memory-style. It has the `MODE=ORACLE` option (as part of the URL) set.

The error message is:

```
SQLException: 90079 Schema "TERMIN" not found
```

The SELECT is:

```
select crm.id, crm.surname, crm.firstname, grp.departm, grp.team
, termin.prev, termin.host, termin.final, termin.kenn
from client_member as crm, company_group as grp, base_process as termin
where crm.id = grp.crm_id and crm.crm_id = termin.crm_id (+)
and crm.pers_id not like 'B%'
and trunc(sysdate) between grp.date_from and nvl(grp.date_to, sysdate)
and ... ;
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does H2 interprete the table alias as schema identifier?

Comment: Probably the Oracle flavoured outer join with `where <join_column1> = <join_column2> (+)` is a problem for H2!